# How can I install elementaryOS's terminal "pantheon-terminal" on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, dependencies, elementary-os

I am trying to install elementaryOS (Juno)'s terminal emulator on Mint 19 Tessa. I checked the instruction at the git hub site https://github.com/elementary/terminal, and I installed all dependencies by using `sudo apt install`.

After I ran the instructed command `meson build --prefix=/usr`, I saw the error output as following:

`Native dependency granite found: NO found '0.5' but need: '>=5.2.0' meson.build:25:0: ERROR: Invalid version of dependency, need 'granite' ['>=5.2.0'] found '0.5'.`

I found the version of this library for Ubuntu is different (though Ver 0.5 is the latest for Ubuntu), but Debian's one is satisfiable. So, I went to Debian package site and downloaded a Debian package libgranite-dev (5.2.3-1), but it wouldn't be installed because the GDebi installer said the dependency was not satisfiable.

How could I cope with this situation to run meson successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is called `pantheon-terminal`, available from the elementary repositories, you can enable the repository to build the dependencies `libgranite5`, then disable it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt build-dep pantheon-terminal
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I finally installed the pantheon-terminal on Mint!!!
By the way, I found the second command line should be
`sudo apt-get build-dep pantheon-terminal` :)

Comment: I cannot vote up your answer because I still haven't had over 15 reps yet. I will come back and vote your answer after I get more than 15 reps :)

Comment: As of July 2020, Linux Mint doesn't appear to allow the addition of the elementary-os PPA. I get an error that 'This PPA does not support focal'.

Comment: this PPA ppa:elementary-os/stable not work? this show a 404 message